# Complex Type not mapping in WSDL PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, complextype

I'm new to WSDL's and am running into an issue with a complex type. Basically its as if the input message is not using the complexType as the type for the input message.

I purposely misspelled the namespace on the output message so I could return what was being passed to the server. What is returned is everything that is sent in the client code. What i would expect, if for soap to cast any type to match the WSDL and to strip any extras, or at least throw an error.

Is there something wrong with my code, or with my understanding of what should happen to the input?

Thanks in advance.

Client:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/Service_v1.wsdl', array("trace" => 1));

$request['UAT'] = 'fdgdfg';
$request['TemplateID'] = '236';
$request['To'] = 'email@address.com';
$request['From'] = 'mail@address.com';
$request['Org'] = 'PPRG';
$request['Order'] = 'order_number';
$request['Fake'] = 'fakefake';
$request['DeliverTimestamp'] = '2012-09-01 00:00:00';


var_dump($client->newEmail($request));

echo "<br><br><br>" .htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest() );
```

Server:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");


class CreateEmail {

function newEmail($request) {
    return array('Status' => $request, 'ReferenceID' => 123);
    }
}


$server = new SoapServer("Service_v1.wsdl");

$server->setClass("CreateEmail");

$server->handle();
```

WSDL:

```
<definitions name="Service_v1"  targetNamespace="http://example.com/Service_v1" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="TransactionDetail">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">                    
                    <xsd:element name="UAT" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="TemplateID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="To" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="From" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Org" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Order" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DeliverTimestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</wsdl:types>

<message name="CreateEmailRequest">
    <part name="emailInfo" element="tns:TransactionDetail"/>
</message>

<message name="CreateEmailReply">
    <part name="Status" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <part name="ReferenceID" type="xsd:integer"/>
</message>

<portType name='CreateEmailPortType'>
    <operation name='newEmail'>
        <input message='tns:CreateEmailRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:CreateEmailReply'/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name='CreateEmailBinding' type='tns:CreateEmailPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

    <operation name='newEmail'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#newEmail'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>

        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name='CreateEmailService'>
  <port name='CreateEmailPort' binding='CreateEmailBinding'>
    <soap:address location='http://example.com/CreateEmail.php'/>
  </port>
</service>

</definitions>
```